# Is there a way how to run MATLAB script from specific line without GUI?

Tags: scripting, matlab

Is there a way how to run MATLAB script from specific line without using GUI.

In GUI I use `%%`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the answer is 'no': see
http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/01/07/ive-got-something-to-cell-you/
comments 27 and 28.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to write to a function, that will read the script m-file, skip the lines until required one and write the rest to temporary m-file, then run it. Or from line1 to line2. Sorry, don't have access to Matlab right now to implement it. May be tomorrow, unless somebody will volunteer to do it.

**UPDATE**

Here is the function:

```
function runfromto(mfile, lfrom, lto)
% Runs mfile script from line lfrom to line lto.
if nargin < 1
    error('No script m-file specified.');
end
if ~strcmp(mfile(end-1:end),'.m')
    mfile = [mfile '.m'];
end
if ~exist(mfile,'file')
    error(['Cannot access ' mfile])
end
M = textread(mfile,'%s','delimiter','\n');
if nargin < 2
    lfrom = 1;
end
if nargin < 3 || lto > numel(M)
    lto = numel(M);
end
if lfrom > numel(M)
    error(['Script contains only ' num2str(numel(M)) ' lines.'])
end

for k=lfrom:lto
    try
        evalin('base',M{k})
    catch ME
        error('RunFromTo:ScriptError',...
            [ME.message '\n\nError in ==> ' mfile ' at ' num2str(k) '\n\t' M{k}]);
    end
end
```

**UPDATE 2** Corrected following comments from *anon*.

Comment: Replace M = textread(mfile,'%[^\n]'); with M = textread(mfile,'%s','delimiter','\n'); and it works. (This reads in blank lines as well. So line numbers match text editor.)

Comment: **This only works for very simple scripts**. Already a `for` loop spanning more than one line will fail :-(

Comment: @ann: Good point! I'll change it. Sorry for delay, I missed your comment somehow.

Comment: @Jonas: Of course, the user have to take care which lines to run. I don't want to write another m-file parser.

Answer (score 0):

A quite elegant way to solve this problem is to use the goto implementation of Husam Aldahiyat:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26949-matlab-goto-statement

Simply put

```
goto("your line") 
return
```

at the beginning of your matlab script.