# Matlab - Do action after every line

Tags: matlab

Is there an elegant way to tell matlab to perform a predefined action after the execution of every line in a certain script? By elegant I mean no calling of the action after every line, but rather something like a simple command given at the start of the script.

Example:
Action --> `disp('Performing Action');`

script:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
```

So the desirable outcome is that after each assignment (of a, b and c), the disp() command would be performed.

Comment: Q1 - you want this to be automatic?  Q2 - What should it say in each line?  Do you want it to display what the action was? Q3 - is your code a **script** or a **matlab function**?

Comment: Q1 - preferably add a certain command at the that would do the trick. Q2 - it should do whatever I tell it. the disp() was an example. Q3 - function.

Comment: Yes, remove the semicolons.

Answer (score 5):

You can automatically create a modifed file that has the desired action included at the end of each line:

```
action = 'disp(''Performing Action'');'; %// action to be added at the end of each line
file = 'script.m';                       %// original script
file_out = 'script_out.m';               %// modified script with action added 
x = importdata(file);                    %// cell array of strings. Each line of the
                                         %// original file is a string
x = strcat(x, {' ; '}, action);          %// add action at the end of each string,
                                         %// preceded with `;` in case the original line
                                         %// didn't include that
fid = fopen(file_out, 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', x{:});              %// write output file
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: You just creating a "non-elegant" (according to OP) file. :)

Comment: At least it's a single piece of code that does this, as opposed to copying the command manually after each code.

Comment: @Kostas Agreed: _non-elegant_ according to OP's definition. But _automatic_ :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo yeap! Actually, what the OP wants cannot be done. There is an inherent complication that it would be written somewhere. Either at the built-in code of MATLAB or at the user's code.

Comment: @LuisMendo, what about overloading `display` function? If at the end of each line of code  the user puts more that 1 `;` (eg. `a=1;;;` your code could be modified in order to find it, compute the number of `;` and use it to enter in a `cellarray` to select the corresponding string to be displayed.

Comment: @il_raffa Sorry, I don't follow. What does `display` have to do with this? The OP [said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135718/matlab-do-action-after-every-line/32137053?noredirect=1#comment52171518_32135718) it was just an example, or at least that's what I understood (the question is not terribly clear). And even if the desired action was `display`, how would overloading it help?

Comment: @LuisMendo my understanding of the objective of the OP is to have a sort of `log` printed during the execution of its function; If so, having it displayed at every single line of code seems  quite strange (it will slow down the execution and the `log` will result unreadable. The `display` function could be overloaded in order to print a string. The user might decide to have the string printed by just not adding `;` at the end of the line of code; unfortunately this works only for 1 string.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1;
disp('Performing Action');
b = 2;
disp('Performing Action');
c = 3;
disp('Performing Action');
```

Or, if you can do this in a loop

```
for ii = 1:3
    a(ii) = ii;
    disp('Performing Action');
end
```

Actually making it output something after every line is not very matlab, but you could of course just loose all the semicolons and thus make it display all variables if you want to track where in the script you are.

I'd suggest a `verbose` switch in your code. Set it to 0 for no output and 1 for output (or use multiple levels if so desired)

```
if verbose > 0
    disp('Performing Action');
end
```

This way you can easily switch the output on or off, depending on need.

For the code-reading and appending piece, see  Louis Mendo's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137053/5211833

Comment: You either misunderstood me, and did not read all of my request =]
I specifically said "By elegant I mean no calling of the action after every line, but rather something like a simple command given at the start of the script."

The assignment of a,b,c was just an example. In real practicality, I want to take a long and complicated script, and add one command that would result in an action being performed after each command in the script.

Comment: Im not sure whether that's possible in Matlab, but I'll look into it. Why do you want the exact same action after every single line of code?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no better solution.

Comment: @A.Visser: Regarding your last edit: The idea is good but the code has multiple errors in it.

Comment: @Daniel : thought as much. Im not a hero in writing files and this is such a weird idea that I havent even tested it. If you can point out the errors that'd be good, or I'll just delete the piece of code, depending on what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. You can:

- read the function line by line
- execute each line, followed by your custom function.

**NOTE**

- This won't work with functions containing `for`, `if`, etc..
- You can eventually improve the code by passing a function handler with your *custom action* to `runEachLine` (and `feval` with that).

Here a code sample (partly based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349594/5008845)):

foo.m

```
function foo(args)   
a = args{1};
b = 2;
c = a + b;
end
```

runEachLine.m

```
function runEachLine( mfile, args )

if nargin < 1
    error('No script m-file specified.');
end
if ~strcmp(mfile(end-1:end),'.m')
    mfile = [mfile '.m'];
end
if ~exist(mfile,'file')
    error(['Cannot access ' mfile])
end

% Read function file
M = textread(mfile,'%s','delimiter','\n');

% Remove empty lines
M = M(~cellfun('isempty',M));

% Input arguments
assignin('base', 'args', args);

% Skipping first line: function [...] = func_name(...)
% Skipping last line : end
for k=2:length(M)-1 
    try
        % Execute each line
        evalin('base',M{k})
        % Execute your custom function
        disp(['Performing Action: ' M{k}]);

    catch ME
        error('RunFromTo:ScriptError',...
            [ME.message '\n\nError in ==> ' mfile ' at ' num2str(k) '\n\t' M{k}]);
    end
end

end
```

Usage:

```
>>runEachLine('foo.m', {4});
```

Result:

```
>> runEachLine('foo.m', {4})
Performing Action: a = args{1};
Performing Action: b = 2;
Performing Action: c = a + b;
>>
```

Answer (score -2):

No, there is not.

What you present in your original question is just a simple usage of the `=` operator.

If you want to overload the default behaviour of MATLAB then you should consider creating a class and define the desired behaviour for each operator or function needed.

Comment: The question is more general. What if a line doesn't include `=`?

Comment: "define the desired behaviour for each operator or function needed". The part saying "for **each**" is the answer to your comment.

Comment: See [this OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135718/matlab-do-action-after-every-line/32137053#comment52162199_32135896): "_The assignment of a,b,c was just an example. [...] I want to take a long and complicated script, and add one command that would result in an action being performed after each command in the script._"

Comment: My previous comment is still valid. Please read carefully my answer. I stated that the request cannot be done. **IF** there is a way, then this would be defining a class and overloading **EACH** needed operator **or** function. This means that, for **EVERY** needed operation **or** function the OP should overload the default behaviour.

Comment: Besides the fact that overloading all possible operators and functions would not be practical, __it wouldn't work__. Say you overload `=` and `find` because they are used in the script. Then in a line such as `c = find(a);`, the action would be called __twice__, and none of those calls would be __after__ the statement contained in that line.

Comment: Since (as it seems) you understood the error in both of your previous comments, now I agree that it would not be practical. I did not stated (anywhere) that it would be :) .  Regarding the double calling, the OP did not stated anywhere that he wanted a summary of the operations performed or single (i.e. for **each** operator/function) briefing.

Comment: The first line in the question says _perform a predefined action after the execution of every line_. Your answer doesn't do that

Comment: `goto comment[1]` (zero based index)

Comment: Again: that wouldn't perform the action __AFTER__ every line as the OP wants. Do you agree on that?

Comment: Downvoting as not constructive.